# Why do I need to double click on the last image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML document with an `img` element and an array of img `src` values. I also have a script that changes the `img` src to a another image every time its clicked. It works fine except that I noticed you have to click the last image twice to get the image array to reset. Why do I need to click it twice?

```
<img src="image1.jpg">

<script>
    let images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image5.jpg"];  
    let imgIndex = 0; 

    $("img").click(function() {             
        if (imgIndex === images.length) {
            imgIndex = 0;
        } else {          
            imgIndex++
        }

        $(this).attr("src", images[imgIndex]);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-based, while the length reports the actual number of elements. So the last array element is images[4], not images[5]

Answer (score 6):

It's because of this:

```
if(imgIndex===images.length)
```

The `length` of the array is **5** (`length` starts counting from **1**), but the highest index in the array is **4** (indexes start counting from **0**), so that condition will never be true. So, you are always directed to the `else` block, where `imgIndex` is incremented.

To correctly determine when the counter has reached the last array index, change the line to:

```
if(imgIndex===images.length - 1)
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Agreed. But, this is the answer to the question.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I didn't realise the OP had set the `0` element as the source manually in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Becouse arrays indexes started with 0, so the last element have index "array.length - 1". So, to make it works properly all you need to do is replace 'images.length' by 'images.length - 1' in your condition statement.

```
if(imgIndex===images.length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the **modulo operator** (`%`) to keep `imgIndex` withing the array boundaries like:

```
$("img").click(function() {             
    imgIndex = (imgIndex + 1) % images.length;

    $(this).attr("src", images[imgIndex]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use the modulo.

You declare imgIndex at 1 and incrementing it when you use the attr method.

```js
var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image5.jpg"];  
var imgIndex = 1; 

$("img").click(function() {             
  imgIndex = imgIndex % images.length;
  console.log(imgIndex);
  $(this).attr("src", images[imgIndex++]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="image1.jpg">
```

Comment: @freedomn-m yeah, it can be confusing but I like to use it as I'm lazy and I don't want to writte another line :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the array goes from `0` to `length-1` so checking against length will get two results.

Change to:

```
if (imgIndex === (images.length - 1))
```

An alternative is to increment the index *first* then check if `>= length`.

```
imgIndex++;
if (imgIndex >= images.length) {
    imgIndex = 0;
```

In addition, you should always check for `>=` to also catch the case where the **global** value is changed to something larger than the array length, as this would mean the `===` never matches.   (which has been the cause of many security bugs over the years).